# Can not see Paypal Button in view

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, paypal

I am not seeing Paypal Button in my ViewController.

```
UIButton *button = [[PayPal getPayPalInst]getPayButtonWithTarget:self andAction:@selector(payWithPayPal) andButtonType:BUTTON_278x43];
```

Above is my code. I am not getting it with any `ButtonType`. It is showing me this in Log...

```
Printing description of button:
<nil>
```

instead of this...

```
Printing description of button:
<UIButton: 0x72c6020; frame = (0 0; 278 43); opaque = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x72bc910>>
```

I am new in iPhone so, any idea will be a great help for me.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have missed this code in your previous class from where you are coming to your current class. You need to initialise PayPal first :-

```
[[PayPal getPayPalInst] fetchDeviceReferenceTokenWithAppID:@"APP-80W284485P519543T" forEnvironment:ENV_SANDBOX withDelegate:self];
[[PayPal getPayPalInst] setLang:@"it_IT"];
```

Hope this helps you..

Comment: It shows - instance method "fetchDeviceReferenceTokenWithAppId" is not found... I used paypal Delegate.

Comment: have you declared #import "PayPal.h" ?

Comment: Yes I do... paypal.h and ExpressCheckoutResponseHandler.h

Comment: have you imported latest PayPal library?

Comment: Yes.. then also if u have any link of that then please send me..if i used my own button then it is working but paypal button is not working...

Comment: Check this link :- https://www.x.com/sites/default/files/paypalmecl_1-0-3_iphone_developerspackage.zip